# Ordered JSON when using Volley (Android)

Tags: android, json

I have some JSON returned from my web-service like below:

```
{
    "error": false,
    "users": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "username": "user001",
            "level": 10,
            "last_updated": "22072014"
        }

        {
            "id": "2",
            "username": "user002",
            "level": 11,
            "last_updated": "21072014"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm building up a long list of items for each user and I want just display them to the screen in the order that they are listed (so id, then username, level, last_updated, etc).

From this post: [JSON order mixed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up) 
"An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs" - I understand that JSONObjects are unordered maps. There is a suggestion of using LinkedHashMap to retrieve the ordered information.

I'm using Volley with a request similar to below:

```
    JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
            URL, params, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){ .. }
```

Is it possible to use the LinkedHashMap or is there any way of maintaining the order of each users attributes as they are received?

Answer (score 0):

Try ObjectMapper in [databind](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.fasterxml.jackson.core%7Cjackson-databind%7C2.4.1.3%7Cbundle)

in fasterxml, it can convert json to object including LinkedHashMap.

update:
a year ago i found this when I needed to iterate json members: [Iterate Json data from web service in correct order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519769/iterate-json-data-from-web-service-in-correct-order)

you can try this:

```
    public <T> T fromJSON(String input, Class<T> clazz) {
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(input != null ? input : "null", clazz);
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
 LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList> fromJSON = fromJSON(
                json, LinkedHashMap.class);
```